# warning: assignment to int ** from incompatible pointer type const int (*)[3]

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem assigning the pointer of a matrix to a double pointer, which will be used next, as follow:

```
const int COLOR_MAP_INDIA[16][3] = {{ 140, 67, 46 },{ 0, 0, 255 },{ 255, 100, 0 },{ 0, 255, 123 },{ 164, 75, 155 },{ 101, 174, 255 },{ 118, 254, 172 },{ 60, 91, 112 },{ 255, 255, 0 },{ 255, 255, 125 },{ 255, 0, 255 },{ 100, 0, 255 },{ 0, 172, 254 },{ 0, 255, 0 },{ 171, 175, 80 },{ 101, 193, 60 }};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int **COLOR_MAP;

    COLOR_MAP= COLOR_MAP_INDIA;
}
```

the compiler says:

> warning: assignment to int ** from incompatible pointer type const int
> (*)[3]

What's wrong ?

Comment: TLDR:  Something like `int **COLOR_MAP` ***never*** refers to an actual two-dimensional array.  When incorrectly called a "2-d array" or similar, it usually refers to a one-dimensional array of pointers to multiple individual, separate, and independent one-dimensional arrays of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is segmentation fault when you even only read via `COLOR_MAP`.

It is defined as containing pointer(s) (to value(s)), not values in rows of three.

Where COLOR_MAP has the values `140, 67,`, it expects the address of the first row.

The abstract type indicated by the warning can be used:

```
int (*COLOR_MAP)[3];
COLOR_MAP= COLOR_MAP_INDIA;
printf("%d\n", COLOR_MAP[2][1]);
```

The `const` mismatch is the same, just less dramatic.

---

**Array-of-pointers version**

An extra layer of pointers can be used to give names to these RGB triplets aka colors:

```
int orange[] = {140,67,46};
int blue[] = {0,0,255};
int greenblue[] = {0,255,123};
int purple[] = {200,0, 200};

int *INDIA[] = {orange, greenblue, blue, purple};
int *INDIA_2[] = {greenblue, orange, purple, blue};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int **MAP;

    MAP = INDIA;
    printf("%d\n", MAP[1][2]);   // 123 
    MAP = INDIA_2;
    printf("%d\n", MAP[1][2]);   // 46
}
```

Quite a different approach, but the elements are accessed in the same way, as 2D-array `MAP[1][2]`.

Answer (score 2):

**warning: assignment to int ** from incompatible pointer type const int (*)[3]**

Your compiler is pretty much telling you everything that is wrong. What you need to know is that a pointer to pointer (which, in your case, is COLOR_MAP) is not equal to a pointer to a one dimensional array of 3 integers (COLOR_MAP_INDIA in this case).
Essentially, you might want to think what difference does it make when both of them are pointers. **BUT** the difference comes when you try to access elements around that pointer with pointer arithmetic.

When you write:

`COLOR_MAP_INDIA`

you mean that it is a pointer to a 1D array containing 3 integers (the memory address of { 140, 67, 46 }, which, in fact, is the address of 140). So, when you do something like,

`COLOR_MAP_INDIA + 1`

you would now point to the very next 1D array of 3 integers (the memory address of { 0, 0, 255 }, the first 0 in this case) and **NOT** the second element in the first array.

Pointers are strongly typed because you can perform pointer arithmetic on them and each such arithmetic doesn't necessarily mean an addition/subtraction of 1.

Answer (score 1):

`COLOR_MAP` is defined as a pointer to a pointer to `int`, whereas `COLOR_MAP_INDIA` is an array of 16 arrays of 3 `int`. These types are incompatible. You should define `COLOR_MAP` as a pointer to an array of 3 `int`:

```
int (*COLOR_MAP)[3] = COLOR_MAP_INDIA;
```

Whether this pointer fits your needs depends on what you intend to do in the unpublished part of the code.

Comment: Practically I have different color maps defined at the beginning of the file which will be used depending on a string, so using if-elseif clauses I would assign the pointer of the corresponding map to a more general pointer that will be used to acccess data. I tried your solution but I receive another warning...`warning: assignment to int from const int (*)[3] makes integer from pointer without a cast
   (*COLOR_MAP)[16] = COLOR_MAP_DC;`

Comment: You need `int (*COLOR_MAP)[3]` and not `int (*COLOR_MAP)[16]` (inner dimensions are preserved, the outer dimension decays).

Comment: It should have been `int (*COLOR_MAP)[3] = COLOR_MAP_INDIA;`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes, my bad, this syntax is such a pain.